# A covariant derivative construction with torsion

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, definition, differentiation

Is there a covariant derivative, $\nabla$, that takes into account torsion, $T^\mu_{\;\;\alpha\beta}$, and covariant derivative of the metric equals zero, $\nabla_\alpha g_{\mu\nu}=0$? If yes, is there a unique for for it?

Answer (score 3):

As per [this previous answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/504744/156895), any metric compatible connection takes the form

$$\Gamma = \Gamma_{LC} + K$$
where $\Gamma_{LC}$ is the (torsion-free) Levi-Civita connection and $K$ is the [contorsion tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contorsion_tensor).  If we demand that the torsion tensor vanish, then the only possibility is the Levi-Civita connection; if we allow the torsion tensor to be arbitrary, then there are an infinity of possible metric-compatible connections.